# How to build with required `.dll` in Windows 10 Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to build a project. I have `a.lib` file that I need to use in my project. I know that there are two ways to use this lib:

- add it using `#pragma comment(lib, "a.lib")`
- add it to linker dependencies `Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`

Now, `a.lib` uses [StackWalk64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680650(v=vs.85).aspx) function `DbgHelp`. This library is supplied as `DbgHelp.lib` and `DbgHelp.dll`. I know that I can use it as a `lib` using two ways listed above. But what if I don't want to include it into my project and want to use `DbgHelp.dll`, how can I do that in Visual Studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static library with dynamic dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25706318/11683)

Comment: There's a shade of XY problem here. Why don't you want to use `DbgHelp.lib`? That import library exists for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read up: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a1-static-and-dynamic-libraries/

### Implicit Linkage with an import library (using .lib)

In this case the static-library is an **"import library"**, which automates the process of determining the effective functions in the DLL. This is called **implicit dynamic linkage**.

### Explicit Linkage

If you don't want to use the import library you have to determine all functions by yourself, create corresponding pointers to the addresses of the procedures and use them after that.
Usually there's some InitDLL() function in your client code, which does this.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/64tkc9y5.aspx

The "GetProcAddress"-function can be used to obtain a handle to the function and call it.

This is called **explicit dynamic linkage** and requires also the calls to LoadLibrary() and FreeLibrary() on Windows.

More Info: http://www.equestionanswers.com/dll/what-is-implicit-and-explicit-linking-in-dynamic-loading.php

### Explicit Linkage on Linux

For linux/unix things work differently. If you want to read up: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html

Comment: _requires also the calls to LoadLibrary() and FreeLibrary() on Windows._ - so basically this is what `import library` is doing? how does it know the path to `.dll`s?

Comment: Yes more or less, that is what the import library is for... With the main difference that you can exactly define when you load the library and free it and which functions you reference. On windows, the dll is searched for as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx

Comment: I'm the OP :). Thanks! Also when I package my code into a lib, will the corresponding import library be generated for the `.dll`?

Comment: Sorry, Using the App where I didnt see the original post. What do you mean? If you create a static lib? The static lib, if it uses a DLL, still requires the final executable to also link the import lib and have the dll detectable.

Comment: I mean I've written a function `sum`. Now I want to wrap it as a dynamic library (my.dll) for others to use. But I don't want others to use `LoadLibrary`, so I need to provide `import library` file `my.lib` for them. Will this `my.lib` be generated automatically alongside `my.dll`?

Comment: If you specify __declspec(dllexport) for at least one function to be exported, the import lib will be created, containing all functions having the __declspec(dllexport) attribute infront of them!

Comment: I recommend spending an hour or two on reading this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ez7dh12.aspx

Comment: Got it, sure, will do. Thanks a lot. Best of luck

Answer (score 3):

If you want to call a function that is within a DLL, but don't want to link to the LIB file that imports these functions for you, then you can use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`. (Though if you have the import library and can link to it, why do you want to load these functions manually?)

***IF YOU HAVE THE `DbgHelp.lib` IMPORT LIBRARY, USE IT! LOADING FUNCTIONS MAUNALLY IS ERROR-PRONE IF NOT DONE RESPONSIBLY. USE WITH CAUTION!***

```
// Type definition for a function pointer that can call the function
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *StackWalk64_func)
(
    DWORD,
    HANDLE,
    HANDLE,
    LPSTACKFRAME64,
    PVOID,
    PREAD_PROCESS_MEMORY_ROUTINE64,
    PFUNCTION_TABLE_ACCESS_ROUTINE64,
    PGET_MODULE_BASE_ROUTINE64,
    PTRANSLATE_ADDRESS_ROUTINE64
);

// Within a function . . .

HMODULE hDbgHelpDll = LoadLibrary(TEXT("DbgHelp.dll"));
if (hDbgHelpDll == NULL)
{
    // handle error and return
}

StackWalk64_func funStackWalk64
    = (StackWalk64_func)GetProcAddress(hDbgHelpDll, "StackWalk64");

if (funStackWalk64 == NULL)
{
    // handle error and return
}

// funStackWalk64 is valid and ready to use
```

Now you can call `funStackWalk64` like the function `StackWalk64`, and pass the function pointer around the place. When you're done using the library, you should free the module handle:

```
FreeLibrary(hDbgHelpDll);
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually (and in Visual C++ specifically,) the `lib` file that comes with a `dll` is what is called an "import library". It means that the library has no actual function bodies in it; it is just there to appease the linker and instruct it to generate an EXE (or DLL) that would use the first `dll` at *load time*.

It is so in this case too. Since you don't have access to the source code for `DbgHelp` so that you can build it as a real static library, you need to make do with the small import library at link time and the dll file at load/run time.

Note: the whole linking and dynamic linking concepts and mechanisms are obviously a lot more complex than what I have room here to discuss. So, the explanation above is quite narrow and specific to your question.

Comment: thanks, I understand now. So what to do if there is no corresponding import library `some.lib` for a `some.dll`?

Comment: Oh, I missed that part of your question. Look at the other answer (by @MABVT) for explanation of that.